# How can I display variables in each stack frame in Java?

Tags: java-bytecode-asm, bytecode-manipulation, jvm-bytecode

From an exception you can print a stack trace of course. But is it possible to see the variables and values in each stack frame using aspects and/or Java agents?

Comment: Read [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jdk/api/jpda/jdi/com/sun/jdi/StackFrame.html): *StackFrames provide access to a method's local variables and their current values.*

Comment: At the point where you catch an exception, the stack frames and hence, the local variables, do not exist anymore. Only the information that has been recorded, does exist.

Comment: @holger is that true? If you are in the catch block you still have not returned yet, so the stack frames are still there. Otherwise how could they trap exceptions that you throw from this frame?

Comment: @robert-harvey  not much documentation on this.  I see the class but not sure how to obtain an instance from an agent

Comment: Of course, the stack frame of the method containing the `catch` block is still there, but getting the variables of your own stack frame is a no-brainer. But the really interesting frames of the methods invoked in the `try` block, down to the place where the exception was actually thrown, are gone. If you’re talking about your caller’s frames, they are still on the stack, but that’s regardless of whether these methods are included in the exception’s stack trace or not (as the exception could originate from a different thread), so it’s an entirely different issue.